# Google test framework и Visual Studio

Tags: c++

На сайте Microsoft, есть статья, как привязать Google test к VS: [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-google-test-for-cpp). Выполнив начальный этап, а именно установка адаптера для этих тестов, я пробую добавить тест к своему проекту, но к сожалению Google test'a просто нету. Нашёл так же расширение "Google test", но это тоже не к чему не привило. Есть у кого-то опыт как грамотно их соединить или возможно я что-то делаю не правильно?

Comment: *"к сожалению Google test'a просто нету"* что тут подразумевается?

Comment: Я пытаюсь добавить к существующему проекту элемент, и в разделе Test, есть только Boost Test, но никак не Google test.

Comment: Следует создать новый проект. Причем никакие особые шаблоны для него не нужны. Обычный exe. Потом обычным образом подключить к нему библиотеку gtest. После сборки этого проекта в Test Explorer должны появиться тесты.

Comment: Обычным образом - это как? Можно пожалуйста по подробнее, это очень поможет.

Comment: Ну указать пути к  заголовочным файлам, указать пути к либам.

Comment: Это всё равно до конца не проясняет ситуацию, я видел решение такого сорта: предлагают склонировать гит проект и из него собрать статическую библиотеку. Но у меня не удалось, возможно я делал что-то не так. Попрошу вас ещё раз описать всё по подробнее, если есть возможность.

Comment: Изначально я предполагал, что у вас уже есть собранный gtest. Если у вас проблемы с его сборкой, то следовало бы задать соответствующий вопрос подробно расписав проблему.

Comment: Есть ли возможность перебраться в другое место и обсудить это по подробнее? как её собрать и в дальнейшем просто использовать подключая include.

Comment: Как я уже написал выше - создавайте соответствующий вопрос. А использовать ее подключая include не получится. gtest (в отличие от boost.test) не является header-only библиотекой.

Comment: Всё, у меня удалось разобраться, тема думаю исчерпана.